# PHP check when a certain function is called

Tags: php, html, debugging, function-calls

I am trying to debug a page someone else has created. There is an insane amount of files in it and I have noticed that some data is stored in the database as if htmlspecialchars was used on it before the insertion.
Is there a way to maybe print a message or something whenever htmlspecialchars is used in the application? Or should I use a debugger?

Comment: A debugger is a pretty good option, yes.

Comment: Agreed.  Use a debugger.